# draw multiple circles and move them

Tags: c++, xcode, cinder

I'm trying to make a small game where a man shoots "bullets" (which are just circles). I have attempted to make it so when someone drags the mouse, multiple circles will spawn. Currently, the circles only travel when the mouse is released. I added a for loop so when I drag the mouse, 30 circles will spawn (clip size) - but when I test it, the circles may spawn, but the circle only stays next to the man until I release the mouse.

```
if(drag == true)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        gl::color(Color(0, 0, 0));
        gl::drawSolidCircle(Vec2f(x, y), 2);
        gl::color(Color(1, 1, 1));
    }
}
```

This is my first time creating a game with c++ or cinder, so sorry if I missed something obvious (simply put, I'm very noobish at coding). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the `MouseDrag()` event?

http://libcinder.org/docs/v0.8.3/classcinder_1_1app_1_1_app.html#a951b397345f8014100cbfd1fc96896b0

Comment: I already have mouse drag. 'void shootingmanApp::mouseDrag( MouseEvent event)
{
    dragX = event.getX();
    dragY = event.getY();
    drag = true;
}' I just can't get it to work so that the circles are separate and move instread of just staying by the man until I let go of the mouse. Thanks though.